# Searchbar that expands to the whole screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-animation

I want to achieve similar effect to the google play books app where searchbar expands and takes the whole screen. Currently I have simple Textfield that sits in Card widget and elevates it and the whole thing is in Appbar. How should I approach it? (I'm using material you 3)

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Card(
      elevation: 2,
      child: TextField(
        autocorrect: false,
        controller: _textEditingController,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {});
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Search",
          border: InputBorder.none,
          prefixIcon: const Icon(
            Icons.search,
          ),
          suffixIcon: _textEditingController.text.isEmpty
              ? null
              : IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
                  onPressed: _clearTextField,
                ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

[image: example]

Comment: I think u should start from hero transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build it with [`showSearch`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showSearch.html)

```dart
showSearch(context: context, delegate:MySearchDelegant ())
```

```dart
class  MySearchDelegant extends SearchDelegate{
  @override
  List<Widget>? buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            query = "";
          },
          icon: const Icon(Icons.clear),
        ),
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget? buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
   return IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back));
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
  return SizedBox.shrink();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
   

   ///return filter Items on ListView
    return ListView();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also wonder what can be used to create animation like in the gif from the google play books, should I use hero transition?

Comment: You can try with `AnimatedBuilder`  also It seems using sizetransition

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to achieve is a [SearchDelegate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SearchDelegate-class.html#:%7E:text=SearchDelegate%20class%20Null%20safety,can%20be%20customized%20via%20SearchDelegate.). You can see youtube tutorial from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wm3OiFBZ2xI&t=411s&ab_channel=GoogleDevelopers)